# Is it possible to add callbacks functions in android system

Tags: android, callback, keylogger

I'm trying to monitor all keyboard input with root permission.

Is it possible to add a callback function whenever a key has been pressed?
It seems like the problem is in inputConnection class in android source.

Or is there other way to capture the keyboard event outside an app?

Using OnKeyPressed isn't a good way because it is under the "view" class
which can only monitor keypress under current app.

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In Android, SoftKeyboard is an App that is overlaid on other Apps. There is no way I can think of that you can access the keypress unless you provide that SoftKeyboard.

Comment: I am thinking about modify the source code of android system and recompile it into android system.img. Then replace the kernel in real device to the it.